# Using LiveData to set visibility of TextView

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I want to toggle the visibility of a TextView using LiveData. There have been a few other posts on setting the visibility with databinding, but these use Observables, whereas I want to leverage the (newer) LiveData. In particular, use a LiveData.

Using [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters), and a few SO posts, I have already learned that you should correctly align your getter of your observable (LiveData) so that the return type matches the type expected by the setter for the View attribute you want to set. Specifically:

- setVisibility() of View requires an int, whereas I have a LiveData member (so the getter in my ViewModel will also return this type)
- converting this Boolean to View.VISIBLE and VIEW.GONE is possible using a ternary operator. I should also add safeUnbox() in my XML expression to make it a primitive boolean

Using these insights, in my ViewModel class, I have defined:

```
MutableLiveData<Boolean> textHintVisible;
```

After pressing a button, I set this value to False:

```
textHintVisible.postValue(false);
```

(note, I also tried with setValue())

Then, in my layout XML, I have included:

```
<TextView
   android:visibility="@{(safeUnbox(viewModel.textHintVisible) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE)}"
/>
```

But still, my TextView is always visible. To debug, I have added an observer in my activity, and this confirms that my boolean is correctly toggled between true and false:

```
mHintsViewModel.getTextHintVisible().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
   @Override
   public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean newInt) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onChanged: "+newInt);
   }
});
```

But my TextView stays visible all the time. What am I doing wrong? Is it impossible to use LiveData for this? Should I use an additional Converter? Or is my code in principle correct, but is this a bug in Android Studio? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: One thing I have in mind is - have you set your binding to observe liveData? As per documentation https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture you have to set the binding layout to observe lifecycle `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)`

Comment: This was indeed the issue! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I posted it as an answer, so you can accept it and other people can see it's resolved and find the answer, not just in comment :)

Comment: All of the code related tot his LiveData variable would be useful. You mentioned "so the getter in my ViewModel will also return this type" BUT "converting this Boolean to View.VISIBLE and VIEW.GONE is possible using a ternary operator." tells me the getter can return a Boolean but ternary will convert to int in place however it doesnt seem to work as described. Really we are just missing the getTextHintVisible() method.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

One thing I have in mind is - have you set your binding to observe liveData? As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture) you have to set the binding layout to observe lifecycle `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)`

Comment: for Fragments use `binding.setLifecycleOwner(viewLifecycleOwner)`

Comment: @Francis Why would we use the fragment's activity as the life cycle owner? Isn't the whole point of this to have the UI attached to the Fragment's life cycle, not the Activity that holds it? Please provide documentation explaining your comment.

Comment: You don't use activity, in Fragment there are actually 2 LifecycleOvwners - 1) the fragment itself, 2) fragment's view. Since instance of fragment is not destroyed after orientation change, only its view is, it is necessary to setup binding's lifecycle to the view's one, otherwise memory leaks may happen.